# Parse SaveEventually Issue in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm facing an issue with save eventually.

I'm retrieving an object from **Parse** the object contains a pointer for a User.
[image]

I'm trying to update the object and save it with a different user.

```
object.incrementKey("Likes")
object.addObject((PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId)!, forKey: "LikesUsers")
object.saveEventually()
```

it works once or twice and then it generates this Error and the app crashes :

> Caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException" with reason "User cannot be
>   saved unless they have been authenticated via logIn or signUp

**I think the user pointer shouldn't be saved ! and I would like to know if there is any function to tell Parse to not save the User and modify the dirty value.**

Comment: You shouldn't add `.objectID` - just add `PFUser.currentUser()` but what is `object`?  Is it a user other than the current user?

Answer (score 0):

You should explain what kind of object we're looking at. Is this a "likes" object, or is the "photo" object?

I'm guessing `object` is a photo or sth that other users kan like. And that what you're trying to do is to save a "like" for the current photo.

Your screenshot is not showing us the LikesUsers column, which is the one you are trying to save to. I will therefore guess that LikesUsers is an array of pointers.

Your code should then be like this:

```
object.incrementKey("Likes")
object.addObject(PFUser.currentUser()!, forKey: "LikesUsers")
object.saveEventually()
```

For this to work, the current user must of course be authenticated already.

Be aware that if you have a lot of users, you may face problems if there are thousands of likes on a photo when you store them all in an array of pointers.

Comment: Thanks for your response, LikesUsers is an array of string which has an objectids of users rather. the problem comes from the from which has a pointer to another user

Comment: What is "from" in this scenario? And you should not store objectids directly. Parse will handle the pointer correctly if you add a User object to the pointer array.